# Font in Bristol west Insurance logo

Tags: font-identification, logo

What is the font in Bristol West Insurance Logo?
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top bold is [ITC Avant Garde Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/avant-garde-gothic/). Not sure about the second.

Edit: Both are ITC Avant Garde Gothic.

Comment: How about the 'B'? :) I was guessing some kind of Garamond but didn't think it was worth it to check :P